# How to parameterize a boolean expression in Linq?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a Linq statement that looks something like:

```
Report.Where(a=>a.Property == 1 || a.Property == 2 || a.Property == 3).Count()
```

I would like to know if I can refactor the statement into something of the form:

```
Report.Where(a=a.Property == validProperties)
```

where I can store a set of `validProperties` as an array of integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Contains` method

```
var idsToCheck = new List<int> {1,2,3};

var someCount = Report.Where(a=>idsToCheck.Contains(a.Property)).Count();
```

Or call the `Count` first and pass the lambda expression to that.

```
var someCount = Report.Count(a => idsToCheck.Contains(a.Property));
```